# Jquery if/else alert, change color depending on answer

Tags: jquery, if-statement, background

I'd like to make an if / else statement in jquery with an alert box popping up and depening on what I choose the background color of the div should change.

ie)

I have a status light, when I press it, I get an alert, if I press OK it changes color to something else and if I press Cancel, the color is unchanged.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

This is how the code looks right now,

HTML

```
<div id="checklistItem">
    <div class="status1">
        <p class="item1"> Sample item </p> 
    </div>
    <div class="itemInfo1"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.status1{
height:15px;
width:15px;
border-radius:15px;
background:red;
position:relative;
top:20px;
left:10px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.status1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: We would like to see what you have tried so far, where you have failed and only then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, welcome (back) to StackOverflow and thank you for editing more detail into your question!

The solution to this is pretty straightforward. The `if` statement surrounding the `window.confirm` dialog determines what the user selected. If the result is `true`, the user selected "Ok", otherwise the user selected "Cancel". You can read more about this on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm).

From this we can change the background accordingly:

```
$('.status1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    /* Hold $(this) in a variable to prevent having to recall it.
     * Here $this is equal to the element which has been clicked on.
     */
    var $this = $(this);

    if (window.confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        /* If the user selected "Ok", change the background to green. */
        $this.css({backgroundColor: '#0f0'});
    }
    else {
        /* Otherwise the user selected "Cancel", change the background to red. */
        $this.css({backgroundColor: '#f00'});
    }
});
```

A better solution would be to simply introduce a new CSS class:

```css
.confirmed {
    background: #0f0; /* Green background. */
}
```

Then use [jQuery's `toggleClass()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to add or remove the class depending on whether the user selected Ok or Cancel:

```
$this.toggleClass('confirmed', window.confirm("Are you sure?"));
```

The `toggleClass()` method accepts a boolean value (`true` or `false`) as its second parameter, and we are supplying that through our `window.confirm()`. `'confirmed'` is the name of the class we're adding or removing.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4qA2V/).